# Can't import into Magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, import, data

I've got two test products to import. One is exported from Magento and can be imported without issues. 
The other one appears to be almost identical but has been manually created.

I can't figure out what's the problem there.

```
"sku","store_view_code","attribute_set_code","product_type","categories","product_websites","name","description","short_description","weight","product_online","tax_class_name","visibility","price","special_price","special_price_from_date","special_price_to_date","url_key","meta_title","meta_keywords","meta_description","base_image","base_image_label","small_image","small_image_label","thumbnail_image","thumbnail_image_label","swatch_image","swatch_image_label","created_at","updated_at","new_from_date","new_to_date","display_product_options_in","map_price","msrp_price","map_enabled","gift_message_available","custom_design","custom_design_from","custom_design_to","custom_layout_update","page_layout","product_options_container","msrp_display_actual_price_type","country_of_manufacture","additional_attributes","qty","out_of_stock_qty","use_config_min_qty","is_qty_decimal","allow_backorders","use_config_backorders","min_cart_qty","use_config_min_sale_qty","max_cart_qty","use_config_max_sale_qty","is_in_stock","notify_on_stock_below","use_config_notify_stock_qty","manage_stock","use_config_manage_stock","use_config_qty_increments","qty_increments","use_config_enable_qty_inc","enable_qty_increments","is_decimal_divided","website_id","related_skus","related_position","crosssell_skus","crosssell_position","upsell_skus","upsell_position","additional_images","additional_image_labels","hide_from_product_page","custom_options","bundle_price_type","bundle_sku_type","bundle_price_view","bundle_weight_type","bundle_values","bundle_shipment_type","associated_skus"
"Test4No",,"Default","simple",,"base","Test4NoImport",,,,1,"Taxable Goods","Catalog, Search","695.0000",,,,"test4-no-import","Test4NoImport","Test4NoImport","Test4NoImport",,,,,,,,,,,,,"Block after Info Column",,,,"Use config",,,,,,,," ","sw_featured=No",,"0.0000",1,0,0,1,"1.0000",1,"10000.0000",1,1,"1.0000",1,0,1,1,"1.0000",1,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
"Test4",,"Default","simple",,"base","Test4Import",,,,1,"Taxable Goods","Catalog, Search","19.0000",,,,"test4","Test4","Test4","Test4",,,,,,,,,,,,,"Block after Info Column",,,,"Use config",,,,,,,,,"sw_featured=No",,"0.0000",1,0,0,1,"1.0000",1,"10000.0000",1,1,"1.0000",1,0,1,1,"1.0000",1,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

That csv won't import, wihtout line 2 it's working nice.

The error is always:

> General system exception happened
>   Additional data: Notice: Undefined index: in /var/www/html/app/code/Magento/CatalogImportExport/Model/Import/Product/Type/AbstractType.php on line 496

Saved via LibreOffice, tried UTF8-BOM, UTF8.
I hope someone is able to spot the issue!?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you want to import bundle product?

Comment: if you want to import simple or config product, you need to only keep required column in csv file. No need to keep extra column in csv file.

Comment: It's a simple product. I'd like to import the given data and there seems to be a mistake inside which I am not able to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for 2 days I finally found the answer.
`country_of_manufacture` contained a space. Once set to nothing, it worked finally ... very difficult to find mistaked where one can't see them but now it seems to be so silly :-S

Answer (score 0):

for the import it's base on your setting language.
Example: 
My setting is :
 
- English -> English
- Vietnam -> Tiếng Anh

The country name on import file is a translate of your setting language.